# Running multiple sites on the same python process

Tags: django, gunicorn

In our company we make news portals for a pretty big number of local newspapers (currently 13, going to 30 next month and more in the future), each with 2k to 100k page views/day. Since we are evolving from a situation where each site was heavily customized to one where each difference is a matter of configuration or custom template, our software is already pretty much the same for all sites. Right now our deployment strategy is one gunicorn instance for each site (with 1-17 workers each, depending on the site traffic), on a 16-core server and 12GB RAM. The problem with this setup is that each worker (regular pre-forked gunicorn) takes 110MB, whether its being used or not. Now with the new sites we would need to add more RAM to serve not that much many requests, so basically it doesn't scale. Also, since we are moving from this model where each site is independent, each site has its own database and I quite like it that way, especially since we are using relational databases (mysql, but migrating to pgsql), so its much easier to shard this way.

I'm doing some research and experimenting with running all sites on one gunicorn instance, so I could use the servers fully and add more servers behind a load balancer when it came to it. The problem is that django assumes in a lot of places that only one site is running per process, so for what I've thought of so far I'd have to implement:

- A middleware that takes the HTTP_HOST from the request and places an identifier on a threadlocal variable.
- A template loader that uses that variable to load custom templates accordingly.
- Monkey patch django.db.model.Model, probably adding a metaclass (not even sure that's possible, but I think I would need it because of the custom managers we sometimes need to use) that would overwrite the managers for one that would first call db_manager(identifier) on the original manager and then call the intended method. I would also need to overwrite the save and delete methods to always include the using=identifier parameter.
- I guess I would need to stop using inclusion_tag decorators, not a big problem, but I need to think of other cases like this.
- Heavy and ugly patching of urlresolvers if I need custom or extra urls for each site. I don't need them now, but probably will at some point.

And this is just is what I came up with without even implementing it and seeing where it breaks, I'm sure I'd need many more changes for it to work. So I really don't want to do it, especially with the extra maintenance effort I'll need, but I don't see any alternatives and would love to learn that someone already solved this in a better way. Of course I could also stop using django altogether (I already have many reasons to do so) but that would mean a major rewrite and having two maintain two incompatible branches of the software until the new one reached feature parity with the django version, so to me it seems even worse than all the ugly hacks.

Comment: Isn't this *exactly* what the Sites contrib is for?

Comment: The sites contrib assumes all sites are on the same database and you add a foreign key to each Model. Besides, it doesn't cover my requirement of having custom templates for each site.

Comment: Sure it does. You can just use some identifying piece from the Site object in your template path.

Comment: For that I'd need to change everything that uses templates (includes, render_to_response and even generic views) to use the site identifier, and anyway by custom templates I meant templates that come first in the template search order (like site_app/app/template.html comes before app/template.html, because site_app is before app in INSTALLED_APPS) and extend the original, so no it doesn't cover that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered looking into why your individual threads are so large?  110MB for a WSGI thread is more than a bit excessive.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't done so yet. This is a large legacy code I've inherited so I assume it does all sorts of inefficient stuff, but I'm looking into running multiple sites together as a way to scale better in the future. Even if I cut this 110MB by half, it won't be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've recently developed an e-commerce system with similar requirements -- many instances running from the same project sharing almost everything. The previous version of the system was a bunch of independent installations (~30) so it was pretty unmaintainable. I'm sure the requirements still differ from yours (for example, all instances shared the same models in my case), but it still might be useful to share my experience.

You are right that Django doesn't help with scenarios like this out of the box, but it's actually surprisingly easy to work it around. Here is a brief description of what I did.

I could see a synergy between what I wanted to achieve and `django.contrib.sites`. Also because many third-party Django apps out there know how to work with it and use it, for example, to generate absolute URLs to the current site. The major problem with `sites` is that it wants you to specify the current site id in `settings.SITE_ID`, which a very naive approach to the multi host problem. What one naturally wants, and what you also mention, is to determine the current site from the `Host` request header. To fix this problem, I borrowed the hook idea from `django-multisite`: https://github.com/shestera/django-multisite/blob/master/multisite/threadlocals.py#L19

Next I created an app encapsulating all the functionality related to the multi host aspect of my project. In my case the app was called `stores` and among other things it featured two important classes: `stores.middleware.StoreMiddleware` and `stores.models.Store`.

The model class is a subclass of `django.contrib.sites.models.Site`. The good thing about subclassing `Site` is that you can pass a `Store` to any function where a `Site` is expected. So you are effectively still just using the old, well documented and tested `sites` framework. To the `Store` class I added all the fields needed to configure all the different stores. So it's got fields like `urlconf`, `theme`, `robots_txt` and whatnot.

The middleware class' function was to match the `Host` header with the corresponding `Store` instance in the database. Once the matching `Store` was retrieved, It would patch the `SITE_ID` in a way similar to https://github.com/shestera/django-multisite/blob/master/multisite/middleware.py. Also, it looked at the `store`'s `urlconf` and if it was not None, it would set `request.urlconf` to apply its special URL requirements. After that, the current `Store` instance was stored in `request.store`. This has proven to be incredibly useful, because I was able to do things like this in my views:

```
def homepage(request):
    featured = Product.objects.filter(featured=True, store=request.store)
    ...
```

`request.store` became a natural additional dimension of the `request` object throughout the project for me.

Another thing that was defined on the `Store` class was a function `get_absolute_url` whose implementation looked roughly like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self, to='/'):
    """
    Return an absolute url to this `Store` or to `to` on this store.

    The URL includes http:// and the domain name of the store.

    `to` can be an object with `get_absolute_url()` or an absolute path as string.

    """
    if isinstance(to, basestring):
        path = to
    elif hasattr(to, 'get_absolute_url'):
        path = to.get_absolute_url()
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            'Invalid argument (need a string or an object with get_absolute_url): %s' % to
        )

    url = 'http://%s%s%s' % (
        self.domain,
        # This setting allowed for a sane development environment
        # where I just set it to ".dev:8000" and configured `dnsmasq`.
        # The same value was also removed from the `Host` value in the middleware
        # before looking up the `Store` in database. 
        settings.DOMAIN_SUFFIX,
        path
    )

    return url
```

So I could easily generate URLs to objects on other than the current store, e.g.:

```
# Redirect to `product` on `store`.
redirect(store.get_absolute_url(product))
```

This was basically all I needed to be able to implement a system allowing users to create a new e-shop living on its own domain via the Django admin.